# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' but requires type "Something else"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using the following codes..

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Comments(int? Id)
    {
        var abccomment= db.xyzComments.Include(c=>c.XYZMasters);
     var comments = (from x in abccomment
                        where Id == x.CcId
                        select x.Comment).Distinct().ToList();

        return View(comments);
    }
```

and my view is

```
@model IEnumerable<Pharman.Models.XYZMaster>
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {

        @item.XYZComment.Comment
    }
```

I get the following error: 
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[farma.Models.XYZMaster].

pls help... TIA

Comment: this is similar to this post:-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813307/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-but-this-dictionary-req

Answer (score 7):

Type of your `ViewModel` is `IEnumerable<Pharman.Models.XYZMaster>` but you are passing `List<string>`

You should change your `ViewModel` type to `IEnumerable<string>`

Then:

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
@foreach (var comment in Model)
{

    @comment
}
```